# Pick distinct rows based on two tables T-SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

Consider the tables in image

> [image]

How to select rows from Table1 excluding items from Table2 with same ReferenceId?

The result should be

> [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can JOIN the tables on ReferenceId, using a LEFT OUTER join and restrict the return values to where the ReferenceId is NULL on Table2.

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ReferenceId = Table2.ReferenceId
WHERE Table2.ReferenceId IS NULL
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use something like:

```
SELECT  Id
        ,ReferenceId
FROM    Table1
WHERE   ReferenceId NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT ReferenceId FROM Table2);
```

Comment: While this works on the sample data, I don't think it works for the stated requirement

Comment: Hmm, question is not completely clear to me then... I'll have another look.

Comment: This question is pretty interesting, and the answers too. See http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/00538/1 for some comparisons in query results :-)

Comment: You see the differences if you say that the last row of table 2 is (3,4) instead of (3,5)

Answer (score 3):

> How to select rows from Table1 excluding items from Table2 with same ReferenceId?

then exclude `ReferenceId` by `t2.ReferenceId <> t1.ReferenceId`

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.ReferenceID FROM t1 
INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t2.ReferenceID <>  t1.ReferenceID;
```

## [*See this SQLFiddle*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e4da4/8)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT table1.id, table1.ReferenceID from table1 
     inner join table2 on table1.id = table2.id
EXCEPT
SELECT id, ReferenceID from table2
```

Answer (score 0):

Query it with condition

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 t1
 JOIN Table2 t2 on t1.Id = t2.Id
    AND t1.Id <> t1.ReferenceId
```